# Errors with architecture

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I added lib from githab to my project.
I have this errors
How can i fix it?

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect", referenced from:

```
    -[MHTransitionShowOverView animateTransition:] in MHTransitionShowOverView.o
      -[MHTransitionShowOverView startInteractiveTransition:] in MHTransitionShowOverView.o
      -[MHTransitionShowShareView animateTransition:] in MHTransitionShowShareView.o
      -[MHTransitionDismissMHGallery animateTransition:] in MHTransitionDismissMHGallery.o
      -[MHTransitionDismissMHGallery startInteractiveTransition:] in MHTransitionDismissMHGallery.o
      -[MHImageViewController centerImageView] in MHGalleryImageViewerViewController.o
  "_CMTimeGetSeconds", referenced from:
      ___54-[MHGallerySharedManager createThumbURL:successBlock:]_block_invoke in MHGallerySharedManager.o
  "_CMTimeMakeWithSeconds", referenced from:
      ___54-[MHGallerySharedManager createThumbURL:successBlock:]_block_invoke in MHGallerySharedManager.o
  "_MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification", referenced from:
      -[MHImageViewController removeAllMoviePlayerViewsAndNotifications] in MHGalleryImageViewerViewController.o
      -[MHImageViewController addMoviePlayerToViewWithURL:] in MHGalleryImageViewerViewController.o
  "_MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification", referenced from:
      -[MHImageViewController removeAllMoviePlayerViewsAndNotifications] in MHGalleryImageViewerViewController.o
      -[MHImageViewController addMoviePlayerToViewWithURL:] in MHGalleryImageViewerViewController.o
  "_MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification", referenced from:
      -[MHImageViewController removeAllMoviePlayerViewsAndNotifications] in MHGalleryImageViewerViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVAssetImageGenerator", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MHGallerySharedManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVURLAsset", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MHGallerySharedManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MPMoviePlayerController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MHGalleryImageViewerViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: you are running the project on simulator so you need to compile the lib for simulator first then run.

Comment: @Pandey_Laxman, how can I do it?

Comment: you need to find the compilation guide for simulator for that lib, or let me know the lib url so I can search for you

Comment: You need to link with the appropriate Apple libraries (AVFoundation, etc).  This information will be easy to search for now that you know what to look for.

Comment: @borrrden, this solved 3 errors from 10, thanks